# node.js http-proxy how to set timeout and a handler on request

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

I am using http-proxy on node.js. I have a proxy request to another server. my requirement is that the proxy request should timeout in 10 seconds. Also when the time out happens, I should be able to display a custom message to user

I have the below code

```
var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();
  req.on('error', function (err,req,res){
       res.send("An error occured");
  });
  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: port,
    headers:req.headers,
    timeout:10000
  })
```

This sets the timeout (due to reasons not known, it times out in 17 secs) but the callback is never executed. It just shows the standard browser message

```
The connection was reset
          The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**:

I tried

```
proxy.on('proxyError', function (err,preq,pres) {
    pres.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    pres.write("An error happened at server. Please contact your administrator.");
    pres.end();
  });
```

This time the method gets invoked, but it complains that the response is already sent, so cannot set headers

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try this :

```
proxy.on('error', function(err, preq, pres){     
    pres.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    pres.write("An error happened at server. Please contact your administrator.");
    pres.end();
});
```